# Win API, update Static controll every X seconds

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I want to update the static controll (simple program that draws text on the window) every X seconds...

The problem is, I dont know which part of WndProc is updating every time (so I can put a timer on it)..

I've tried using threads, the problem is, it gets inside the thread, but doesnt create the text (the CreateWindowW function), it skips it/it just doesnt work.. (checked with debuger)

What can I do ?

Here is my code in WndProc, WM_CREATE, and I'm creating the controll inside the "Display Notefication" function...

```
        case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CenterWindow(hwnd); // Centering the window
        CreateMen(hwnd); // Creating the menu
        thread t1(DisplayNotefications, hwnd); // Displaying text
        t1.detach();
    }
    break;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you creating the control?  The thread should only need to update it by setting the text.

Comment: I'm creating it inside the function...
So where should I create the control? since WM_CREATE is only being called once, I need a place that will create the controll again and again, and meanwhile in the thread I will update the text, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to update static text in x seconds, why don't you just use `SetTimer`, there's a sample here [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which send a window message to WndProc every x seconds.

Comment: But I need to update it every X seconds, not in X seconds, which means It needs to happen a lot of times... 
SetTimer only happens once, right ?

Comment: Unless you don't stop the timer (using KillTimer), the event will happen every X second.

Comment: as @mox said, it will repeat unless you kill it with KillTimer.